# Co-Related SubQuery

Tags: sql, plsql, subquery

Gahh.. Frustrating me. The textbook asks us to rewrite the following statement without using co-related subqueries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT V.VENDOR_NAME, I.INVOICE_NUMBER, I.INVOICE_DATE, I.INVOICE_TOTAL 
FROM VENDORS V
JOIN INVOICES I 
    ON V.VENDOR_ID = I.VENDOR_ID
WHERE I.INVOICE_DATE IN 
    (SELECT MIN(INVOICE_DATE) FROM INVOICES IV WHERE IV.VENDOR_ID = V.VENDOR_ID)
AND I.INVOICE_NUMBER IN 
    (SELECT MIN(INVOICE_NUMBER) FROM INVOICES IV WHERE IV.VENDOR_ID = V.VENDOR_ID)
ORDER BY V.VENDOR_NAME
```

How can I do that? I can't think of anyway to re-write it without a subquery :S

Comment: A bit of a strange query, if `INVOICE_DATE` AND `INVOICE_NUMBER` aren't their minimum values for the same invoice, it won't show any results at all.

Comment: I wonder why the textbook has DISTINCT on this query. That's a bit of a code smell that they haven't put the right uniqueness constraints on the tables involved, or haven't bothered to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it as a simple `LEFT JOIN` with no subqueries at all;

```
SELECT DISTINCT V.VENDOR_NAME, I.INVOICE_NUMBER, I.INVOICE_DATE, I.INVOICE_TOTAL 
FROM VENDORS V
JOIN INVOICES I 
    ON V.VENDOR_ID = I.VENDOR_ID
LEFT JOIN INVOICES I2
    ON V.VENDOR_ID = I2.VENDOR_ID
   AND (I2.INVOICE_NUMBER < I.INVOICE_NUMBER OR
        I2.INVOICE_DATE   < I.INVOICE_DATE)
WHERE I2.INVOICE_NUMBER IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5d97/7).

Comment: :O I never thought that was possible.. This solution works! I have to study this solution now. Figure out why LeftJoin replaces the SubQueries.

Comment: +1 the correlated subqueries are effectively doing the same work as a left join (as long as the correlation results in no more than 1 record for each record in the first table), so they can usually be trivially rewritten as left joins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT V.VENDOR_NAME,
    I.INVOICE_NUMBER,
    I.INVOICE_DATE,
    I.INVOICE_TOTAL 
FROM VENDORS V
    JOIN INVOICES I 
        ON V.VENDOR_ID = I.VENDOR_ID
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            VENDOR_ID,
            MIN(INVOICE_DATE) MIN_INVOICE_DATE,
            MIN(INVOICE_NUMBER) MIN_INVOICE_NUMBER
        FROM INVOICES
        GROUP BY VENDOR_ID
    ) MV
    ON V.VENDOR_ID = MV.VENDOR_ID
       AND I.INVOICE_DATE= MV.MIN_INVOICE_DATE
       AND I.INVOICE_NUMBER = MV.MIN_INVOICE_NUMBER
ORDER BY V.VENDOR_NAME
```